# Why do I get E127 from this vimscript?

Tags: python, vim

I have the following vimscript .vim/ftplugin dir:

```
" change to header file from c file or vice versa
function! CppAlter()
python << endpy
import vim
import os
bufferNames = [os.path.basename(b.name) for b in vim.buffers]
currentBufName = vim.eval("expand('%:p:t')")
currentBufStem, currentBufExt = os.path.splitext(currentBufName)
if currentBufExt == ".cpp" or currentBufExt == ".c" or currentBufExt == ".cc":
    altBufName1 = currentBufStem + ".h"
    altBufName2 = currentBufStem + ".hpp"
    if altBufName1 in bufferNames:
        vim.command("b " + altBufName1)
    elif altBufName2 in bufferNames:
        vim.command("b " + altBufName2)
    else:
        raise ValueError("No header file corresponding to this c file")
elif currentBufExt == ".h" or currentBufExt == ".hpp":
    altBufName1 = currentBufStem + ".cpp"
    altBufName2 = currentBufStem + ".c"
    altBufName3 = currentBufStem + ".cc"
    if altBufName1 in bufferNames:
        vim.command("b " + altBufName1)
    elif altBufName2 in bufferNames:
        vim.command("b " + altBufName2)
    elif altBufName3 in bufferNames:
        vim.command("b " + altBufName3)
    else:
        raise ValueError("No c file corresponding to this header file")
else:
    raise ValueError("This is not a c type file")
endpy
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>vc :call CppAlter()<cr>
inoremap <leader>vc <esc>:call CppAlter()<cr>
```

When I open vim I get an error:

```
" vim.error: Vim(function):E127: Cannot redefine function CppAlter: It is in use
```

But if I save it in /tmp and explicitly :so /tmp/x.vim, there is no error msg.
Wondering what is wrong here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Inside your function, you're loading another buffer (e.g. `vim.command("b " + altBufName1)`). When that buffer has the same filetype, the current ftplugin script is sourced again as part of the *filetype plugin* handling, but the original function hasn't returned yet, so you get the `E127`.

#### Solution

I recommend putting the function itself into an *autoload script*, e.g. in `~/.vim/autoload/ft/cppalter.vim`:

```
function! ft#cppalter#CppAlter()
    ...
```

Your ftplugin script becomes much smaller and efficient, as the function is only sourced once:

```
nnoremap <leader>vc :call ft#cppalter#CppAlter()<cr>
...
```

(You should probably use `:nnoremap <buffer>` here to limit the mapping's scope.)

#### Alternative

If you don't want to break this up, move the function definition(s) to the bottom and add a guard, like:

```
nnoremap <leader>vc :...

if exists('*CppAlter')
    finish
endif
function! CppAlter()
    ...
```

Comment: The autoload approach gives this error: E117: Unknown function: ft#cppfunc#CppAlter

Comment: The autoload function name and the file location must correspond to each other exactly!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered an interesting case of `E127`, which pretty much sums up why it would occur in almost any situation. Let me explain.

First, let's look at what the docs say.

```
                                                                E127 E122
                        When a function by this name already exists and [!] is
                        not used an error message is given.  There is one
                        exception: When sourcing a script again, a function
                        that was previously defined in that script will be
                        silently replaced.
                        When [!] is used, an existing function is silently
                        replaced. **Unless it is currently being executed, that
                        is an error.**
```

For the next part notice what the last line has to say.

Let's understand this by an example. Below is a function that guesses and sources the current script based on what filetype it has. Notice how the `exec` command will initiate an endless recursive sourcing of the current file on calling this function.

```
function! s:SourceScriptImplicit()
  if !&readonly
    w
  endif
  let l:bin=system("which " . &filetype)[:-2]
  let l:sourcecommand=
        \ #{
        \ vim:         "source %",
        \ sh:          "!source %",
        \ javascript:  "!node %",
        \ python:      "!python3 %"
        \ }
  exec l:sourcecommand[split(l:bin, "/")[-1]]
endfunction
```

To fix this, simply remove the recursive part out of the function.

```
function! s:SourceScriptImplicit()
  if !&readonly
    w
  endif
  let l:bin=system("which " . &filetype)[:-2]
  let l:sourcecommand=
        \ #{
        \ vim:         "source %",
        \ sh:          "!source %",
        \ javascript:  "!node %",
        \ python:      "!python3 %"
        \ }
  return l:sourcecommand[split(l:bin, "/")[-1]]
endfunction

nn <leader>so :exec <SID>SourceScriptImplicit()<cr>
```

Now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should notice that `|` can be useful for execute command in the bottom command line,such as `:source expand("%") | source ./awesome.vim`
Here is my `.init.vim`(or `.vimrc`) snippet whose func is sourcing all `.vim` files in `/home/zarkli/.config/nvim/myInitCustom/` directory:

```
function SourceVimScripts() 
    let l:command = ""
    let l:files = split(globpath('/home/zarkli/.config/nvim/myInitCustom/','*.vim'),'\n') " use absolute path to avoid problems when opening an non-nvim_init file
    for l:file in l:files
        let l:command .= "source ".l:file." |"
    endfor
    " the end of the l:command should be '|',but that doesn't matter
    return l:command
endfunction
exec SourceVimScripts()
```

It can perfectly deals with your problem.